# Need help parsing Flat XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, arrays, string, parsing

I'm having a real issue trying to **parse an XML file** that is structured in the following way **using PHP**.
As you might notice, they are key->value pairs, but it could be **key->string** or **key->data** etc.

Anyone got an idea? I'd really appreciate the help.
Also, data is from an external interface and I have no control over it's formatting.

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>John</string>
        <key>surname</key>
        <string>Smith</string>
        <key>Car</key>
        <string>Ford</string>
        <key>picture</key>
        <data>AAAA====</data>
        <key>age</key>
        <string>32</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I would like to somehow re-format the data with something simple, such as:

```
array
  -dict
    -name=John
    -surname=smith
```

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at simplexml class: http://php.net/simplexml

Also, XML has a standard, so even though your XML is coming from external interface, they should be a standard, valid XML.

EDIT

```
<?php
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>John</string>
        <key>surname</key>
        <string>Smith</string>
        <key>Car</key>
        <string>Ford</string>
        <key>picture</key>
        <data>AAAA====</data>
        <key>age</key>
        <string>32</string>
    </dict>
</array>
XML
;

$tmp = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
$var = (array)$tmp->dict;
$keys = array();
foreach($tmp->dict->children() as $k => $v) {
        if($k == 'key') $key = (string)$v;
        else $keys[$key] = (string)$v;
}

print_r($keys);
```

Comment: I've been using SimpleXML, but it seems to convert my XML into three arrays (key, string, data), and of course I can't just map the arrays as the indexes would get messed up

Comment: It'll be much easier for me to help you if you post your attempt in PHP and what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: $tmp = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
$var = (array)$tmp->dict;
var_dump($var);   - This is it so far. I can't get the data into the right structure.

Comment: Thank you very much andreas - I really appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
$temp = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$array = array();
foreach($temp->dict->children() as $value) {
    if($value->getName() == 'key') {
        $key = (string)$value;
    } elseif($value->getName() == 'string') {
        $array[$key] = (string)$value;
    } elseif($value->getName() == 'data') {
        // possibly treat data differently, or maybe not
        $array[$key] = (string)$value;
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

It tries to gather up the keys and values and assign them to the array as it goes.

Comment: This is almost perfect, except it wouldn't support anything other than [string], such as [data] (in the example)

Comment: Thank you very much Martin - I really appreciate it :-)